# Linux Mint: All Notifications Sound the Same After Update

Tags: linux-mint

I'm using Linux Mint, and just upgraded to version 21.1.

Previously, different applications on my computer made different sounds to notify me.  Discord had one sound, Slack had another, Safe Eyes (a program I use to remind me to take breaks) had another, and so on.

However, since the update they've all been merged into some sort of notification manager system thing, and they all have the same identical sound.

Is there any way to revert it back to each app having their own sound, or just disable the new notification system entirely?

Answer (score 1):

I found *a* solution:

1. Go to the Linux Mint menu (eg. hit the Windows key on your keyboard)
2. Choose System Settings
3. Pick Notifications
4. Switch "Enable notifications" off.

However, while doing this restores the unique sound from each application, it also hides the visual notification.

So, I'm still looking for an answer that allows the notifications to appear on screen ... just with their own unique audio.